# Select statement of a table SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, matrix, representation

I have a table with 3 columns, representing a matrix:

```
i j val
-------
1 1  1
1 2  12
1 3  4
2 1  3
2 2  4
2 3  4
3 1  0
3 2  2
3 3  2
```

How would I select this table in such a way  i get

```
a1 a2 a3
-------
1 12  4
3  4  4
0  2  2
```

Is there a way to use pivot or what would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [1] AS a1,
       [2] AS a2,
       [3] AS a3
FROM T
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR j IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS P
```

Comment: Excuse me, and lets suppose I have the number of rows (in the example was 9), is there a way to make a dynamic version of your great code?

Comment: @cMinor - Yep. I'm sure [one of the answers to your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A265519+sql-server+dynamic&submit=search) should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am a little late to the party, but isn't this closer to what you are looking for:

```
SELECT [1] as a1, [2] as a2, [3] as a3
FROM
(
SELECT i, j, val
FROM T) AS source
PIVOT
(
    MAX(val)
    FOR j IN ([1], [2], [3])
) as pvt
```

Also, [this link](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx) discusses generation of columns dynamically.

Good Luck!

Matt

Comment: what is the difference @Matt... could you please explain a little?

Comment: Martin Smith's query worked, but it gave back a row for each value (unless I did something incorrectly).  So you end up with nine rows for a1, a2, & a3.  The query I posted above returns exactly what you put in your question as the desired output (3 rows).

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - You must have done something incorrectly. Like adding a superfluous column to your test table. [Online Demo](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59767)

Comment: @MartinSmith--Yes, I did add an identity column.  I didn't realize that was incorrect, and assumed that the OP has an ID column in his actual data.  For our education, can you please briefly let us know why that would be superfluous or incorrect?  Not giving you grief, I just would like to know for the sake of bettering myself.  Thanks!

Comment: `PIVOT` implicitly groups by any columns in the table source not explicitly used elsewhere in the query aggregate or pivot list (so all columns other than `val, j` in this case). It is a bit like using `*` and has the same hazards in that if the table definition is later changed the PIVOT query breaks so in fact your approach is more defensive (+1).

Comment: @MartinSmith--Ok.  Thanks for the explanation and the vote up.  Both are appreciated!